# Why is Google Analytics constructed the way it is?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

the google code for insert google analytics:

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=174090

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

why just insert directly code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="true" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: ? I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: because your why don;t they do it this way code is wrong, uses `www` instead of `ssl` :)

Comment: @Yosef - do you need any more information here? I believe the question was answered

Answer (score 3):

They state the reason why they use the asynchronous snippet in that document you linked:

> One of the main advantages of the asynchronous snippet is that you can
>   position it at the top of the HTML document. This increases the
>   likelihood that the tracking beacon will be sent before the user
>   leaves the page. It is customary to place JavaScript code in the
>    section, and we recommend placing the snippet at the bottom of
>   the  section for best performance.

Comment: i asking why not insert directly the script location nad not why async

Comment: @Yosef its the same thing. The indirect insertion causes it to be injected asynchronously in many browsers that don't explicitly support the `async` attribute. The protocol is part of it, but this is more important. Otherwise, they could just do `<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js</script>` and it would load using the appropriate protocols.

Answer (score 2):

It is done in this way, so it can load js file using right protocol (http:// or https://)

Answer (score 2):

The GA code is an universal snippet to include the script at each page, using the appropriate protocol. Pages served at the https-protocol load the GA script over a secured connection. Pages at other protocols are served via the normal (http) protocol.

The significant part of the code is shown below:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

Equivalent to:

```
if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
    ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
} else {
   ga.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
}
```

Comment: but if i am programmer i can do the code that i suggest right?

Comment: @Yosef If you're managing a big website, where pages are served over both secure (HTTPS) and normal connections, the original code is the best way to go. If you are 10000% sure that you're never going to use https, your suggested code is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Because they need to make sure they have the protocol correct.  They need to communicate over HTTPS, when the tracked page is communicated over HTTPS.

Comment: soo i can put the https url also if my page over http

Comment: If you feel fine going to every page you have, and determining whether or not you use http or https on that page, that is fine by me.  I will put this in my template page ***once*** and never look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

I know that if IE loads content over a https ssl connection, it won't load anything linked via http, so your tracking code would never get loaded.